# Nginx loads same web for all domains

Tags: nginx, debian

I have two domains, fav2feed.com and elciervonegro.com in the same server, nginx, all setup by myself (newbie).
if I only put one domain in sites-enabled, they load fine induvidually. Buy when I try to have both online at the same time, both domains load elciervonegro.com.

Here are my sites-available:

fav2feed.com

```
server {
listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /var/www/fav2feed;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name fav2feed.com;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}


#error_page 404 /404.html;


# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

elcievonegro.com

```
    server {
  listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
  #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

  root /var/www/elciervonegro;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name elciervonegro.com;

  location / {
  # First attempt to serve request as file, then
  # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
  # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
  }

  location /doc/ {
  alias /usr/share/doc/;
  autoindex on;
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  allow ::1;
  deny all;
  }


  #error_page 404 /404.html;


  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  #
  location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  # # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
  #
  # # With php5-cgi alone:
  # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  # # With php5-fpm:
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

Comment: for server administration, please consider migrating the question to [sf] (or asking there in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

I've got to fix it by starting setup from a clean template using default file on sites-available, couldn't fix it otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by using identical `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` in the `nginx` server blocks (if you copy one domain configuration to another).

If you are running `php-fpm` in a `chroot` with different `listen ports` it will appear as if `nginx` is serving the same website for both domains.